# iPhone App: Sync Google Calendar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, google-calendar-api

In iPhone App I want Integrate Google calendar.

How to sync Google Calendar to an iPhone App?

Is there any sample code or Tutorial  available for that?

Where to start to sync Google Calendar? ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the link for Google Calendar OBJ-C API

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FExamples%2FCalendarSample